# Genymotion show an error in android studio

Tags: android

I am just a beginner in android programming,
 I use Genymotion to run virtual devices on android studio , The virtual device is open when I run Genymotion. But when I run it from android studio to run the application, it shows the following error: I hope my question is clear and understandable

> ```
> Cannot reload AVD list: cvc-enumeration-valid: Value '280dpi' is
> not facet-valid with respect to enumeration '[ldpi, mdpi, tvdpi, hdpi,
> xhdpi, 400dpi, xxhdpi, 560dpi, xxxhdpi]'. It must be a value from the
> enumeration. Error parsing
> C:\Users\g\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\system-images\android-22\android-wear\armeabi-v7a\devices.xml
> cvc-enumeration-valid: Value '280dpi' is not facet-valid with respect
> to enumeration '[ldpi, mdpi, tvdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, 400dpi, xxhdpi,
> 560dpi, xxxhdpi]'. It must be a value from the enumeration. Error
> parsing
> C:\Users\g\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\system-images\android-23\android-wear\armeabi-v7a\devices.xml
> cvc-enumeration-valid: Value '280dpi' is not facet-valid with respect
> to enumeration '[ldpi, mdpi, tvdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, 400dpi, xxhdpi,
> 560dpi, xxxhdpi]'. It must be a value from the enumeration. Error
> parsing
> C:\Users\g\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\system-images\android-23\android-wear\x86\devices.xm
> ```

Comment: not sure exactly, but somewhere you have this value `Value '280dpi'` which is not valid for the emulator, maybe it can't start a wearable platform? as it says `Error parsing...android-wear\armeabi-v7a\devices.xml`

Comment: i try to change the dpi of the emulator in genymotion,,, but still giving the same error in android studio.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please delete Android Wear ARM & Intel images like image shows.

[image]